# AvalonDock add tab dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I am trying to add tabs dynamically using AvalonDock with WPF, but I am not able to do it.

Do you have a clue whar is wrong?

**The code for adding tabs dynamicaly**

```
public DockView()
{
    MyDocuments = new ObservableCollection<DocumentContent>();   
    InitializeComponent();

}


public void CreateView()
{
    string baseDocTitle = "MyDocument";
    int i = 1;
    string title = baseDocTitle + i.ToString();

    while (dockManager.Documents.Any(d => d.Title == title))
    {
        i++;
        title = baseDocTitle + i.ToString();
    }

    MyDocuments.Add(new DocumentContent() { Title = title });
}
public ObservableCollection<DocumentContent> MyDocuments { get; private set; }
```

**XAML Code**

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Documents">
        <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="Create New" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
<ad:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager" Grid.Row="2"
                   DocumentsSource="{Binding MyDocuments}">
    <ad:ResizingPanel>
        <ad:DocumentPane />
    </ad:ResizingPanel>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use features (binding) that aren't available in release 1.3 of AvalonDock.

The good news is - the original author is re-writing the library to be MVVM-friendly :)

Check out the link:

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Version2Concept&referringTitle=Home

The new version just went into Alpha so will be around 2 months away from being production-ready but you can play with it for now.

If you can't wait and need a MVVM friendly version of 1.3 in the meantime, I suggest the solution presented in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff798279.aspx

Steve

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on using AvalonDock with MVVM:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239342/AvalonDock-and-MVVM

Hope it helps.